# D3D11 Writing to buffer in geometry shader

Tags: opengl, windows-7, directx, direct3d, directx-11

I have some working OpenGL code that I was asked to port to Direct3D 11.
In my code i am using Shader Storage Buffer Objects (SSBOs) to read and write data in a geometry shader.

I am pretty new of Direct3D programming. Thanks to google I've been able to identify the D3D equivalent of SSBOs, RWStructuredBuffer (I think).

The problem is that I am not sure at all I can use them in a geometry shader in D3D11, which, from what i understand, can generally only use up to 4 "stream out"s (are these some sort of transform feedback buffer?).

The question is: is there any way with D3D11/11.1 to do what I'm doing in OpenGL (that is writing to SSBOs from the geometry shader)?

**UPDATE**:
Just found this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404562%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If i understand correctly the section "Use UAVs at every pipeline stage", it seems that accessing such buffers is allowed in all shader stages.
Then i discovered that DX11.1 are available only on Windows 8, but some features are also ported to Windows 7.
Is this part of Direct3D included in those features available on Windows 7?

Comment: Is it not explained [in this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj863687(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: Hi Roger, thanks for the link, i did not find it.
However, from that link it's still very unclear what part of D3D11.1 is available on Win7, and more specifically whether UAV access from all shader stages is allowed.
They discuss some difference with the  driver model WDDM1.2 and that's it.
But perhaps i can then try and see if i get a compile error by using one of the access functions in the geometry shader.

Comment: Yes, I think part of that link also says that the features are also dependent on graphics hardware and drivers, so it may be that the only thing you can do is check capabilities and trap errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just been pointed to this page:
http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3196/~/fermi-and-kepler-directx-api-support .
In short, nvidia does not support the feature on cards < Maxell.
This pretty much answers my question. :/

Answer (score 1):

RWBuffers are not related to the geometry shader outputting geometry, they are found in compute shader mostly and in a less percentage in pixel shader, and as you spot, other stages needs D3D 11.1 and Windows 8.

What you are looking for is stream output. The API to bind buffers to the output of the geometry shader stage is `ID3D11DeviceContext::SOSetTargets` and buffers need to be created with the flag `D3D11_BIND_STREAM_OUTPUT`

Also, outputting geometry with a geometry shader was an addition from D3D10, in D3D11, it is often possible to have something at least as efficient and simpler with compute shaders. That's not an absolute advice of course.

Comment: So you say that i can't write to a RWBuffer or RWStructuredBuffer from the GS in Windows7, even using the Platform Update?
I can correctly pull data from SRV buffers, but when i try to write data into a RWStructuredBuffer i get a runtime error "invalid technique xyz". 
The problem is that i get the same error also if i try to write the RWStructuredBuffer from the Vertex Shader, stage in which this operation should be allowed, by specs.
Maybe i am doing something wrong? I simply declared my buffer as:

`RWStructuredBuffer<float4> wb: register( u0 );`
and wrote with 
`wb[idx] = float4(smtg);`

Comment: oh, i also bind the UAV in this way:
`m_effect->GetVariableByName("wb")->AsUnorderedAccessView()->SetUnorderedAccessView(myUAV);`

Answer (score 0):

The geometry shader is processed once per assembled primitive and can generate one or more primitives as a result.

The output of the geometry shader can be redirected towards an output buffer instead of passed on further for rasterization.

See this [overview diagram](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476882%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the pipeline and [this description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205146%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the pipeline stages.

A geometry shader has access to other resources, bound via the [GSSetShaderResources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method on the device context.  However, these are generally resources that are "fixed" at shader execution time such as constants and textures.  The data that varies for each execution of the geometry shader is the input primitive to the shader.